# Counting an Array XNA HLSL

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl

I was wondering how to count an array in HSLS?
Say, I have an array declared in our effect file:

```
float2 Position[1];
```

And inside our source I set the parameter to something else
for instance:

```
Effect.Parameter["Position"].SetValue(MyVector2Array);
```

**Under the shadering function how could I count the array?** Would look similar to:

```
float4 PS_function(float2 tex : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{ int Size = Position.Count(); }
```

Thanks in advance :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simple way is to declare a constant that will define an array size:

```
const static int MAX_POSITIONS = 1
float2 Position[MAX_POSITIONS];
```